# react-native flatlist does not re-render on element update?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-flatlist

So I read that react native FlatList is a `PureComponent`, so it does not re-render automatically. But, my current FlatList re-renders when an element is removed or added (so when the array length changes), but if I try to change an element in the data array without changing the length, the FlatList does not re-render. Is there any way to do this?

I have tried extraData [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#extradata), with a flag in my redux state that changes when the action is dispatched, but it does not work.

Comment: ["```shouldComponentUpdate``` does a shallow comparison"](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate). Write your own checker and return ```true``` when items change

Comment: exactly what I just figured out, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. My FlatList rendered Child1Components, which had a Child2Component (nested in another level), and that component, for some reason, was not updating - only the Child1Component was updated. So I every time I wanted to update something in the nested Child2Component, I ran

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ flag: !prevState.flag });
```

in Child2Component to re-render it.